# Match a string with a fixed substring in variable positions

Tags: regex, expression

there:

I want to create a filter in my email server that matches any message that contains any URL (using either http or https protocols) from a certain domain (let's say domain.org). I want it to match things like:

- https://site1.domain.org
- https://anothersite.domain.org
- http://yetanotherone.domain.org

The problem here is that these strings can be wrapped in the message body at any random position of the string. And even worse, when the string is wrapped an equal sign is added before the end of the line, so I would need it to be able to match strings like these:

`ht=
tps://thisisanexample.domain.org`

`https://thisisane=
xample.domain.org`

`https://thisisanexample.do=
main.org`

I came up with a simple (but huge) solution, but I think there must be a much more elegant one than mine:

```
/h[=[:cntrl:]]*t[=[:cntrl:]]*t[=[:cntrl:]]*p[=[:cntrl:]]*s?[=[:cntrl:]]*:[=[:cntrl:]]*\/[=[:cntrl:]]*\/[=[:cntrl:]]*[-+_@&%$#|()=?¿:;,.,çÇ^[:cntrl:][:alnum:]\[\]\{\}\*\\]*[=[:cntrl:]]*.[=[:cntrl:]]*d[=[:cntrl:]]*o[=[:cntrl:]]*m[=[:cntrl:]]*a[=[:cntrl:]]*[=[:cntrl:]]*i[=[:cntrl:]]*n[=[:cntrl:]]*.[=[:cntrl:]]*o[=[:cntrl:]]*r[=[:cntrl:]]*g/
```

I have been looking around but I can not find anything that I understand to improve my solution given that my knowledge of regex does not go beyond simple queries.

Thank you very much in advance.
Regards.

2018/04/11 EDIT: Thank you to everyone who tried but the solutions proposed do not meet the requirements of elegance and readability I was expecting. I was looking for something like capturing everything but the equal-return string and performing the web address string search on the captured result of the first search. Is this a doable idea?

Comment: if you can set up single line, `.*?` can replace `[=[:cntrl:]]*` with the loss of some precision

Comment: when it gets a `=` sign anywhere in the string, does the coming up string goto the next line ?

Comment: Lance, I do not want to loose precision here. I am going to drop mail messages based on this regex, so the more precise, the better

Comment: @ankush-rathi, the `=` sign can appear anywhere in the whole text, but I want to match those that come along with the new line symbol (whichever it could be CR, LF, CRLF, etc.)

Comment: A [named subroutine](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) can help shorten your regex like this `(?(DEFINE)(?'s'[=[:cntrl:]]*))h(?1)t(?1)t(?1)p(?1)s`

Comment: Can you remove all equals signs *before* checking the string?

Comment: @bohemian No, this regex is to be applied to a mail rule and used directly on the mail body text. No further processing to the original text will be done.

Comment: What is the filter written in? For example, sieve filters can operate on various transformations of the message: `if body :content "text/html" :contains "http://thisisanexample.domain.org"` or `if body :text :contains "anotherurl"`

Comment: This filter is to be used directly within a Microsoft Exchange Transport Rule. There is not much to be done to transform the message. It works in a way like "if this regex matches something then apply the rule" and there is no way to perform a previous transformation of the message.